# FIREBASE has been blocked by CORS policay

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

Hi dear devs hope you all have a great time!

I want to clearly describe the problem i stuck in while creating my latest application:

1. In a part of my application i want to implement a feature to my user be able to log in with google account! (i created the username and password login with my express and mongodb before!)
2. so i created a new project in firebase (authentication part) and followed the guide!
3. and did the start guides as firebase explained! but when i want to call a function in my react app to sign in to google i face with "CORS" problems. i will show you necessary parts of code! hope you be able to assist me.

A) installed firebase ("yarn add firebase")

B)craeted a file (firebase.js) in root of my react project and here is the code you can see:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider} from "firebase/auth"
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBwXUkWR49-SmNIrmgzbkT7jZXdAxhwsM4",
  authDomain: "video-4d60e.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "video-4d60e",
  storageBucket: "video-4d60e.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "644740096295",
  appId: "1:644740096295:web:037fb76e08bd5c28664902"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth()
export const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()

export default app
```

C) then i imported the constants i craeted in last part and Also implemented a button and a function  to.              handle google sign in for me, here is the code either"

```
import {auth, provider} from "../firebase"
import {signInWithPopup} from "firebase/auth"


  const signinWithGoogle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
 

<Button onClick={(e) => handleLogin(e)}>Sign in</Button>
```

and this is what is going on in my console tab( NOTE : i am using google chrome!)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC15o.png)

What i did:

i researched lots of time on this issue but i faced with various answeres and i completly confused!

1. a forum says this is because you are not set out Cors in your backend but i am using react without any relations to my express backend! does it really affects?
2. another discussion mentioned that you have to set "google cloud function invoker" but i couldn't figure out how should i do that
3. and another says you have to set "no cors origin" in your request headers!

and lots of more various answeres!

Can anyone help me PLEASE?